# Electron: Length of an array set to 0 after going outside a query

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, electron

I'm starting a project, a kind of interactive text game, on Electron. I have a database with 4 tables to use ONLY at the start of the project, in order to get info of characters, places and staff like.
The problem is that, after getting outside the query, the array when I put the data of characters, says that length is 0, but it show the correct info.
This photo you can see that the array above says it has more than 5 houndred items (this come from another version of the project with others techs), but the line under it, the console.log of the lenght, say it is 0

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6go8C.png

This is the code of the query

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM persona", function (error, rows) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        obtenerPersonas(rows);
    }
})

function obtenerPersonas(rows) {
    rows.forEach(row => {
        /*I try to not introduce the data directly, but using local variables that I previusly create. It doesn't work*/
        auxPer = new Persona(
            row.NombreClave,
            row.NombreMostrar,
            row.Apodo,
            row.Localizacion,
            row.Genero,
            row.Sexualidad,
            row.ActDep,
            row.ComePrimero,
            row.ActPreHombres,
            row.ActPreMujeres,
            row.Prota
        );
        listaPersonas.push(auxPer);
    });
}
/*This are the console.log of the picture, if I put them inside the connection query, they show all perfecty, the array content and length*/
console.log(listaPersonas);
console.log(listaPersonas.length);
```

If you need more info, tell me, please. I need to solve this. Without the length, I can't advance more

Comment: Have you tried returning the `listaPersonas` array *outside*, ***after***, of the loop but inside the `obtenerPersonas()` method, then referencing the method in your log?

Answer (score 0):

`connection.query` is asynchronous function so it's being called after `console.log(listaPersonas); console.log(listaPersonas.length);`. However `listaPersonas` fills up after time, so `console.log(listaPersonas)` shows like this. If you need length then you have to write code after calling the `obtenerPersonas` function.

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM persona", function (error, rows) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        obtenerPersonas(rows);
        // write code here
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could I ask you for a little advice on the code I have to write? Right now, I don't have any idea what it has to be

Comment: Just write there what you want do with `listaPersonas` filled up.